# Abnormal Output of OpenDroneMap with GCP file

Tags: georeferencing, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, ground-control, opendronemap

I am using a gcp_list.txt file with the following text:

[image: gcp_list]

I am supposed to get a geo-referenced mesh object like this:

[image: mesh object 1]

But, I am getting something like this:

[image: mesh object 2]

I am running ODM locally in ubuntu 16 following their doc provided here: https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/ODM

It's written here that if I provide a file named `gcp_list.txt`, it will automatically detect it. So, I have placed the `gcp_list.txt` file in the folder with images and run it according to the doc without any extra flag setting.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you switched the x and y UTM values in your table or maybe you switched the x and y values of the GCP locations in your images.  Also, I cannot remember about how ODM wants the pixel coordinates  but  maybe your pixel values are from the upper left corner when they need to be from the lower left corner or visa versa.

Comment: The gcp_list.txt has been generated using the GCP interface of WebODM. I have seen there that you have to give longitude first, then latitude. And the pixel numbers have also been generated by WebODM. What change should I do now? :|

Comment: Do your images have GNSS values in the EXIF headers?  Your elevations are all the same?  Consider NaN values for the elevations then,  If that fails, try without the GCP file and just georeference the final image to fine tune the output.

Comment: I actually don't have elevation data, that's why I am assigning constant elevation. I don't know about the GNSS thing :| . What value should I set for NaN value setting? I actually need the mesh to be georeferenced, that's why, I have to do it with gcp.

Comment: The constant elevation may be the problem.

Comment: If you are not measuring the GCPs, how had you obtained their coordinates? Can you use just three GCPs along the street instead of 16 GCPs well distributed? Obviously the mesh will not be accurate, but if you are not measuring the control points I think you will not worry about accurate.

Comment: I have manually collected the latitude, longitude values using google maps and used Webodm GCP interface to generate the gcp_list.txt file. That's why, I don't have accurate altitude values. What should I do now with the altitude value? Can you please tell me

Comment: @SifatMuhammadAbdullah, Hi. Use the street. Which must have an approximate same elevation. Use two GCPs or three. Can you test it?

Comment: I am doing it right now. Is it okay if I give only one gcp in an image? And how many total gcp's should I give?

Comment: @SifatMuhammadAbdullah, I am not being automatically notified about your comments. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/478007. I usually check my _All Actions_ section to see if there are something new in the posts in wich I have previously participated. If not, I do not find out that you wrote a comment in your post. Since three unaligned points are needed to define a plane in space, use three points. I dont know if the mesh will be georeferenced with less than three points. But you can test it.

Comment: Okay thank you. I will try it for sure! :D

Comment: @SifatMuhammadAbdullah   - Where is this place located at ?

Comment: It's in Mohammadpur, Dhaka, Bangladesh.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca , I have generated 3D mesh .obj files using road as GCPs and it worked. I want to test whether the 3D mesh are truly georeferenced or not. How can I test that?

Comment: @SifatMuhammadAbdullah, I would try to load it as a Mesh layer in QGIS to check if it is already georeferenced. https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_mesh/mesh_properties.html#loading-a-mesh-layer

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca, can you please tell me how I can convert my ODM output of the 3D .obj and .mtl files to .kmz or citygml file so that I can show them in cesium globe? Or is there any other way to show the ODM mesh outputs in the cesium globe?

Comment: @SifatMuhammadAbdullah, What about your original question? Please, stay in focus. If you want to ask another question feel free to start another post.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca, thank you for mentioning that. Setting gcps on the ground did solve my problem! Thank you everyone :D :D

Comment: Glad to hear your problem is solved.  To finish this post-if you do not have elevation values you could replace your gcp files 50 with text  NaN (not a number).  GNSS values?  I was asking if your images were geotagged.  An easy way to check geotag information is to install EXIFTools.

Comment: @GBG, okay got it. Thanks ^_^

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca, in the ODM Documentation, they say that - 
"The gcp_list.txt file must be created in the base of your project folder." . Can you please tell me which one is exactly the base of my project folder? I am not 100% clear about this.

Comment: @SifatMuhammadAbdullah, Comments are not the place to ask questions. By the way, I don't know that. I was answering you from the photogrammetry point of view. I have not tested the ODM app. Feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: Perhaps this discussion should be compiled in an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in its processing is that it is georeferencing all ground control points with the same elevation, when they clearly do not have the same elevation.

The georeferencing process is not just to place the mesh in a particular geographical location. But to adjust the photogrammetric product to the real dimension of the objects represented in it.

In your case, since you don't have these points measured and you just want to place the mesh in a particular geographical place, regardless of the dimensions of the objects represented, what you could do is define only three control points, located on the street, such that they are supposed to have approximately the same elevation there.

Comment: Yes, setting the gcps on the ground worked :D . Thank you! :D